# How to correctly place Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I correctly place navbar so that it will be in the center with image but aligned to the right, while using best Bootstrap practices (also for responsive layout)?
This code actually works good if there are many links in the navbar, but get displaced with fewer links like this.
If I add `navbar-right` on `ul.nav` then it will aligned to the right but only at beginning of upper ul list.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaOrBR

```
<header>

  <div class="container">

    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive logo col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </a>


    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container container-header">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking? But I think if you add `float:right` to your `.navbar-nav` that's what you're looking for?

Comment: If I add float:right or navbar-right on .navbar-nav than it will look like this http://prntscr.com/b55cba , it doesn't go all the way to the right

Comment: Well, yes, you have another list which is also floating to the right - it will collide with it. Do you want it underneath the other list? Above it? On top of it?

Comment: I would like to have it underneath that list, but using clear: both on nav element will completely displace everything. I would like to have it like this http://prntscr.com/b55iwg.

Comment: Does the markup have to stay the same? Or can you change it around?

Comment: I can change it around but I would like to keep layout in mobile with first ul list in top, then image and lower part navigation. At first I did it by using .row and .col-x-x but I had a problem with links in upper ul list not functioning properly, so I changed it and this code was working quite well. Now we have decided to remove few links and navigation broke :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay try something like this: (I took a container our too, because I wasn't sure why you needed 2!)

```
<header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="right">
          <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
            <li>E</li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive logo col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </a>


    <nav class="navbar">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
        </div>


        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

CSS:

```
img.logo {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.right {
  float:right;
}

.right ul {
  float:right;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works well :) I only moved  <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> inside <nav class="navbar">, not sure why you left that out:)